# Batch File Permanent Variable?

Tags: batch-file, variables, automation

Good Morning,

I am creating a script that will automate part of an installation process. I need to know the file path for each computer I use this script on. I used the set UN=%username% to retrieve the username of the computer I am installing on. However, I also need to run this script as Administrator. When I enter my admin credentials, it changes the %username% variable and also changes my UN variable. Is it possible to set UN to the %username% variable without it changing when I enter administrative mode?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "I also need to run this script as Administrator", in what context? and how? Generally when someone needs to 'Run as administrator' they're taking about running elevated. That is effectively running as the same user, but with a special token allowing greater privileges.

Comment: Normally, when we run these install files, we click Run as Administrator. I'm trying to write the batch file so when it goes to install the files, it runs them as an administrator. That's why I was curious if there is a way to create something similar to a constant variable in a batch file. We were told to install the files as administrator by the vendor who created the software.